# UITabBar images not showing properly on iOS 7

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, icons, uitabbar

I have this Tab Bar working properly on iOS 8 but not on iOS 7 can someone point me in the right direction, i use a JSON file to configure my UITabBar when it loads the first screen.

Do I have to use different images for iOS 7??

It is possible to change the size of de Button to avoid the behavior??

iOS 8:

[image]

iOS 7:

[image]

This is the code I use to load the images:

```
- (void)createTabBar
{
    tabController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"cCustomTabController"];
    dValue = [dConfiguration objectForKey:@"Buttons"];
    NSMutableArray  *aControllers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int i = 0;
    for (NSString* sProperty in dValue) {
        NSString* d = @"Details";
        NetworkStatus internetStatus = [_reachabilityInfo currentReachabilityStatus];
        NSData *itemData = Nil;
        if (internetStatus != NotReachable)
            itemData = [util getSpecificJsonData:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Item"]];
        if(itemData != nil){
            UIStoryboard *aStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *vcCustom = [aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[util getControllerName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ViewController"]]];
            UIImage *imageBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]]];
            UIImage *imageBtnPress = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageHeighlighted"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetinaHeighlighted"]]];
            UITabBarItem *tab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] image:imageBtn selectedImage:imageBtnPress];
            UIImage * iSelected = imageBtnPress;
            iSelected = [iSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            [tab setSelectedImage:iSelected];
            tab.tag = i;
            if([[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] isEqualToString:@"Notificaciones"])
                tab.badgeValue=[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Badge"];
            [vcCustom setTabBarItem:tab];
            [vcCustom setTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"]];
            [aControllers insertObject:navigationController atIndex:i];
            i++;
        }
        else
        {
            UIStoryboard *aStoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main_iPhone" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
            UIViewController *vcCustom = [aStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:[util getControllerName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ViewController"]]];
            UIImage *imageBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]]];
            UIImage *imageBtnPress = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageHeighlighted"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetinaHeighlighted"]]];
            UITabBarItem *tab = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] image:imageBtn selectedImage:imageBtnPress];
            UIImage * iSelected = imageBtnPress;
            iSelected = [iSelected imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
            [tab setSelectedImage:iSelected];
            tab.tag = i;
            if([[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"] isEqualToString:@"Notificaciones"])
                tab.badgeValue=[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Badge"];
            [vcCustom setTabBarItem:tab];
            [vcCustom setTitle:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Title"]];
            UINavigationController *navigationController = [[cCustomNavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vcCustom];
            [aControllers insertObject:navigationController atIndex:i];
            i++;
        }


    }
    tabController.delegate = self;
    tabController.viewControllers = aControllers;
    tabController.tabBar.tintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @MacroAntonioUzcategui  i think you need to assign 2x images. try it and inform me.

Comment: @AshokLondhe my images are 2x and works like a charm in all my retina devices using iOS 8 but with the same images an the same devices in iOS 7 I got that awful behavior. Some how iOS 7 is not working like expected or like in iOS 8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have changed in my code this 2 lines:

```
UIImage *imageBtn = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]]];

UIImage *imageBtnPress = [UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageHeighlighted"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetinaHeighlighted"]]];
```

For this 2:

```
UIImage *imageBtn = [self changeImageSize:[UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"Image"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetina"]]] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];

UIImage *imageBtnPress = [self changeImageSize:[UIImage imageNamed:[util getImageName:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageHeighlighted"] andRetrina:[sProperty valueForKeyPath:@"ImageRetinaHeighlighted"]]] scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(30, 30)];
```

And added this function to change the size of the image:

```
- (UIImage *)changeImageSize:(UIImage *)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, NO, 0.0);
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, newSize.width, newSize.height)];
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return newImage;
}
```

I don't know if this is correct but for me is working.

Thanks to all and happy coding.

Comment: This is a very overkill solution. Have a look at my answer for a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to use asset catalogs containing @1x, @2x and @3x images files to support any screen resolution.

I personally use Mark Bridges' [Asset Catalog Creator](https://itunes.apple.com/app/asset-catalog-creator-app/id809625456?mt=12) to create my different resolutions.

**EDIT:**
Once you imported the multi-resolutions asset catalog, you can use `[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"];`or select it from interface builder. iOS will automatically choose the good one.

Comment: I will give a try to this, thanks for your help, i will tell you if this worked in a few days. I'm in a hurry and I solved it with code, but I think that your solution will be more elegant

Comment: Okay, I look forward to hear from you !

Comment: I have done what you told me an I still have the same issue, the only thing that is working is the code I posted, I'm going to talk with the designer, maybe there is something wrong in the way he is creating the image, a app you posted is really helpful, thanks for your help

Comment: Are your images actually bigger than a tab bar ? The best practice is to use assets of the exact same size as you want them to appear on screen. For a tab bar, they should not be bigger than 49px. Have a look there: http://iosdesign.ivomynttinen.com/

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to use asset catalogs containing @1x, @2x and @3x .

Exemple :
      `yourimageName@2x~iphone.png for iphone` ,

```
  yourimageName@2x~ipad.png for ipad
```